# Splitting field of $x^4 -t$ over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I need to find the splitting field of $f =x^4 -t \in \mathbb{F}_p(t)[x]$, with $p$ prime, distinguishing the cases $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

I solved it in the first case, not the second. Here's what I did:

$p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. I recall $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is cyclic, say it has generator $\alpha$ of order $p-1$. Then take a root $\zeta$ of $f$, say the image of $x$ in $\frac{\mathbb{F}_p(t)[x]}{(x^4 -t)}$, and it is easy to see that $\zeta\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{4}}, \zeta\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{4}\cdot 2}, \zeta\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{4}\cdot 3}$ are also roots of $f$, and they are all distinct thanks to $\alpha$ being a generator. Hence, $\mathbb{F}_p(t,\zeta)$ is the splitting field.

When $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, the $\frac{p-1}{4}$-trick does not work, and I noted that $\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ is just $-1$. I feel in this case I'll have to attach two distinct roots $\zeta_1,\zeta_2$ so that all the roots are $\pm\zeta_1,\pm\zeta_2$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For $ p \ne 2$ the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_p(t^{1/4},\zeta_4)$ (where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity) and for $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ then $\zeta_4 \in \mathbb{F}_p$ so it is $\mathbb{F}_p(t^{1/4})$, for $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ then $\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta_4) = \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ so it is $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}(t^{1/4})$. What about the case $p=2$ ?

Comment: Thanks @reuns, I see that $\zeta_4 \not\in \mathbb{F}_p$ because $-1$ is a quadratic nonresidue. Nice.
The exercise actually didn't ask for $p=2$, but I reckon that in that case $f$ is inseparable, and so $t^{1/4}$ is the only repeated root and $\mathbb{F}_2(t^{1/4})$ is again the splitting field.

Comment: Just to follow up, the exercise continues asking for the Galois groups. I found that  when $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, the Galois group is $C_4$ with generator $t^{1/4}\rightarrow \zeta_4 t^{1/4}$. More importantly, I think I found for $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ that the Galois group is $D_8$, with generators $x \rightarrow x^p$ for $x\in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ (fixing $t^{1/4}$), and $t^{1/4}\rightarrow \zeta_4 t^{1/4}$ (fixing $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$). Does that sound about right?

Comment: For $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and $\phi(\zeta_4^n t^{1/4}) =\zeta_4^{-n} t^{1/4}$ and $\sigma(\zeta_4^n t^{1/4}) = \zeta_4^{n+1} t^{1/4}$ then $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^2}(t^{1/4})/\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)) = \langle \phi, \sigma \rangle \cong  D_4$.

Comment: Davide, yup. Those are the Galois groups. Pretty much the same argument as with the splitting field of $x^4-2$ over the rationals. A warning: there is no universal agreement about how to denote the dihedral groups. For many (including me and apparently also reuns) the group $D_n$ consists of symmetries of the regular $n$-gon, and therefore $D_n$ has $2n$ elements.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much reuns and Jyrki!
I'll try to remember the ambiguity about $D_n$ next time, in the name of inclusiveness.